# What is difference between internal and private in Solidity?

Tags: blockchain, solidity, smartcontracts

In Solidity we have four types of access. Two of them are `private` and `internal`.
What is the difference if both of them can be used inside smart contract and both of them are not visible after deploying?

Comment: By `not visible after deploying` you mean they are not visible (and cannot be used) by a user or another smart contract.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Access types:

`public` - can be used when contract was deployed, can be used in inherited contract

`external` can be used when contract was deployed , can NOT be used in inherited contract

`internal` - can NOT be used when contract was deployed , can be used in inherited contract

`private` - can NOT be used when contract was deployed, can NOT be used in inherited contract

Comment: This was better than the soildity docs

Answer (score 17):

`internal` properties can be accessed from child contracts (but not from external contracts).

`private` properties can't be accessed even from child contracts.

```
pragma solidity ^0.8;

contract Parent {
    bool internal internalProperty;
    bool private privateProperty;
}

contract Child is Parent {
    function foo() external {
        // ok
        internalProperty = true;
        
        // error, not visible
        privateProperty = true;
    }
}
```

You can find more info in the docs section [Visibility and Getters](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.10/contracts.html#visibility-and-getters).

Answer (score 1):

- `public`: anyone can access the function
- `private`: only this smart contract can call this function
- `internal`: only this smart contract and smart contracts that inherit from it can call this function
- `external`: anyone can access this function unless this smart contract

Note that `external` uses less gas than `public` so if the function is not used by your contract, prefer `external` over `public`.

Answer (score 0):

Although there are thorough answers here, another approach I think we could take about these keywords is that:

- `internal` or `external` mentions the way blockchain see the function, e.g. internal the contract itself, external (outside and only outside) the contract.
- `private` or `public` mentions how the inheritance concept in OOP work in solidity.

Good luck to you all.